# Wait until function will done, then submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have code:

```
 function UPLOAD_RP()   {
    document.VideoApplet.UPLOAD_VIDEO(String('<?php echo $video_temp; ?>.mp4'));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitStep3").click(function(){
        UPLOAD_RP();
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

I have java applet that recording video from webcam, then i click on button.submitStep3. Video should upload and after that form should submit. How could i check when upload_rp() over uploading? Thankyou.

Comment: It’s impossible to answer unless we know how the `document.VideoApplet.UPLOAD_VIDEO` function works.

Comment: ok. what if function returns something like true or false. what should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to this `VideoApplet` code, you might consider making it return a *completed* token of sorts, once the upload is done. Then you can base your code off that. Just out of curiosity, a JAVA APPLET? I haven't seen one in years